# Finding an Accurance of a date in a column and copy that and assign to a date column based on the accurance of the date value

Tags: sql

I have a table that has values and but the dates are mixed with them as well if you ask why. This data was gathered from facebook and it provides for a  chunk of demographics one date per JSON batch, but when I have parsed out i need to assign that date to all rows they belong to.

This is what I have in a table.

```
id     Values                    DateCol
 1      132                                 
 2      22                         
 3      33                          
 4     01/20/2019          
 5      43                          
 6      54                          
 7      62                          
 8     02/21/2019
```

I would Like to Have to be Like This.

```
id     Values                    DateCol
 1      132                       01/20/2019          
 2      22                        01/20/2019
 3      33                        01/20/2019
 4     01/20/2019                 
 5      43                        02/21/2019  
 6      54                        02/21/2019  
 7      62                        02/21/2019  
 8     02/21/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you can use `lead(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when value not like '%/%/%'
             then lead(case when value like '%/%/%' then value end ignore nulls) over (order by id)
        end)
from t;
```

However, not all databases support this functionality.

If the dates are increasing (as in the sample data), then the simplest method (apart from the above) is a cumulative minimum:

```
select t.*,
       (case when value not like '%/%/%'
             then min(case when value like '%/%/%' then value end) over (order by id desc)
        end)
from t;
```

However, this would really require that you store the dates in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Gordon, however, This doesn't populate the dateCol with the dates it just put the date on a different column for that date row only, if you look above on my post you will understand it.

Comment: @Senay . . . Nothing in the question suggests unambiguously that you want an `update`.  You also have not tagged with the database you are using.